# Entering in recovery system trouble

Tags: startup, recovery, internet-recovery

When I'm trying to enter in recovery system through pressing cmd+R I'm getting OS X Internet Recovery instead of Utilites window. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine will automatically use Internet Recovery on holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  if it can find no suitable Recovery Partition.

Extrapolation of that is that your hard drive may have had a failure & cannot currently be read by the machine - or simply that there is a bootable drive, but no additional Recovery Partition.

Once Internet Recovery has booted, you may be able to investigate further.